# Java: Add KeyListener to JFrame and its components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, keylistener

I try to add a `KeyListener` to a `JFrame`. This works fine like this.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
[...]
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() { [...] });
```

However, when I have the focus on a button or on a `JTextField` (like when I click on it), that `KeyListener` won't react to my button pushes.

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you know how to fix this?

Yes, use Key Bindings and not a `KeyListener`. The bindings can be set to work even if the bound component doesn't have the focus, one of their key advantages (no pun intended). The tutorial can be found here: [Key Bindings Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Note that when you get the `InputMap` from your bound component, be sure to use the right condition, i.e.,

```
InputMap inputMap = myComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
```

There are three input maps for each component, and the one above will be active when the component is held in a top-level window (such as a `JFrame`) that is currently active. This means that the binding will work even if the component itself doesn't have focus.

---

You can find some of my sample programs that use Key Bindings, often in conjunction with Swing animation, here:

- [Java Animate JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12545773/522444)
- [MouseEntered and KeyPressed at Same Time Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987008/522444)
- [Override VK_Tab Focus action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9286424/522444)
- [How to make an image move while listening to a keypress in Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887354/522444)
- [Java Key Event won't execute once I press a button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9150081/522444)
- [Did I structure this key listener properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23254218/522444)